# scale image 80% - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

Im using media queries to make the text and layout (margins, padding, ect) on my website responsive..

ive set it to "if browser window < 1300px" then change all the measures to 80%. This all works fine, but my images aren't responsive, is there a way to set something similar on my images using jquery to make the img width 80% of its full size (to be in proportion with the rest of the scaled page ?)

the media query im using is :

```
@media only screen 
  and (max-width : 1300px) {
    /* new css */
  }
```

Comment: Why not add the image's css into that same css rule?? If you're hard coding the size in the image tag... don't

Comment: @iight - i cant add the images css, as the image width is set in the html width="" attribute. Although i am hard coding the other css, font sizes, padding ect.. is there another way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will scale `img` elements to 80% if the screen width is less than `1300px`:

```
if ($(window).outerWidth() < 1300) {
    $('img').each(function(){
        $(this).width ( $(this).width () * 0.8) );
        $(this).height( $(this).height() * 0.8) );
    });
}
```

Comment: @AaronBlenkush - thanks but ive set my media query to make the css 80% smaller if the screen is < 1300px so its not set the screen dims. ie. if the screen was 1000px it would still use the messures at 80%. Is there a way to do that with the jquery ?

Comment: @sam Could you simply add an `if` statement to check the `window` width. If < 1300 do this, if >= 1300 do this?

Comment: ahh yes, didn't think of that! if you want to amend your answer ill mark it as accepeted

Comment: @sam I think I understand what you mean now. See the edit. It's a bit different, but I believe it does what you want. I'm not sure what you mean by "so its not set the screen dims"

Comment: @aaron - by "so its not set the screen dims" i meant so that it measures 1300px from the browser window. rather than measuring 1300px from the screen size. (as the bro)

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Aaron's answer, but I think it accomplishes something different since it makes it proportional to the size of the window, but it is not always 80% of its full size.

```
if ($(window).outerWidth() < 1300) {
  $('img').css('width', '80%');
}
```

Comment: This would be simpler than the `.each()` loop, you're correct.

Answer (score 2):

Too bad your image widths are defined by attributes and not by CSS :(

Using a JS solution for something so inherently CSS\design related feels wrong to me. 
How about using a pure CSS solution? Here are some ideas:

## Method  1

Override your hard coded image attributes with hardcoded image css. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/U9aNk/)

```
@media only screen 
  and (max-width : 1300px) {

    img.pasta{
        width: 250px;
        height: 300px;
    }

    img.pizza{
        width: 450px;
        height: 200px;
    }

  }
```

## Method 2

Use css to have images expand to their container dimensions. This will ensure the image expands while maintaining aspect ratio

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}


@media only screen 
  and (max-width : 1300px) {

    .image_container{
        /* lets say that 300px is the "80%" of normal size */
        width: 300px;
     }

  }
```

## Method 3

Get creative and use CSS transformation to scale down the images, without changing their width or height

```
@media only screen 
  and (max-width : 1300px) {
    img{
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
        -moz-transform: scale(0.8);  /* FF3.5+ */
        -ms-transform: scale(0.8);  /* IE9 */
        -o-transform: scale(0.8);  /* Opera 10.5+ */
         transform: scale(0.8);
    }
  }
```

Comment: i agree, it seems to be over complicated using js, or even worse i was thinking of using php to echo a width="" attribute into the html img tag ! What i ended up doing was similar to method2 - as set out in my jsfiddle above

Answer (score 0):

Ive been playing arround with this for a while and found an alternative using media queries and css, using `img {max-width: 100%;}` - no js.. have a look here for the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qEf5J/